# Elementary os Juno intstall external usb

Tags: uefi, usb

Hello im trying to install juno on a external usb of 64 gb using this partitions

disk formatted in MBR and GPT

for bios boot:
20 gb ext4 beginning  primary /root
16 gb swap memory

select boot intallation on external 64 gb usb in MBR install and when install GRUB2 give Fatal error in GPT before install ask to add the EFI partion of at leas 34 mb this complete the installation but dont start during the restart.

on the pc bios boot i see in on the UEFI boot ubuntu and uefi 64 gb usb but if i select that restart and run the dell performance test or restat using the win10 boot

i tried also to make a partition of 2 mb in gparted for the boot_grub in way to avoid to install the grub on win10 drive but dont work

can someone explain in very simple way how install elementary juno available for all pc UEFI and Legacy on external usb without installing file on win10 drive

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with my XPS 13 9730.  It's due to UEFI boot being set in BIOS.  You need to enable Legacy Boot.  I'm trying to work out how to force Elementary OS to install as UEFI because Legacy is much slower.